# Pycharm has arch of arm64 but says that it is running on x86_64

Tags: python

When I write import pygame into my code and run the code, it shows an error that says that I don't have the correct arch (have x86_64, need arm64) even though pycharm terminal says that the current arch is arm64.

[image: error message]

Comment: don't post images of text